# Multiplicative property for the coefficients of cusp form

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

This question might seen as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328916/coefficient-in-the-fourier-expansion-of-the-cusp-form), however my aim is to understand the theory which lies beneath the computations of Sage.

Let $\Gamma_0(4)$ be a congruence subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ defined as

$$\Gamma_0(4)=\{M=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b\\
c& d
\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\mid c=0\bmod 4\}.$$
Dedekind eta-function is defined as
$$\eta(z)=q^{1/24}\prod_{n\geq1}(1-q^n).$$

As it was [beautifully explained](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316464/ideal-of-cusp-forms-for-gamma-04-is-principal) by Noam Elkies, the ideal of cusp forms for $\Gamma_0(4)$ is principal and generated by

$$f(z)=\eta(2z)^{12}=q-12q^3+54q^5-...\,. \,\,\,(1)$$

My questuion is how to prove that the coefficients in the expansion $(1)$ are multiplicative, i.e. $c_nc_m=c_{nm}$ whenever $\text{g.c.d}(n,m)=1.$ As I know this should follows from the theory of Hecke operators of $\Gamma_0(4)$ and the fact that $f(z)$ is an eigenform.

Can anyone give some explanations of this?

Comment: It does follow from the usual argument with Hecke operators. Have you read one of these proofs?

Comment: But we need to consider Hecke operators exactly for $\Gamma_0(4)$ and prove that $f(z)$ is eigenform for all of them, right?

Comment: It is not very hard to prove that something is an eigenvector when the space it lives in is 1-dimensional.