# computing the fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(4) \backslash \mathbb{H}$

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, group-presentation, automorphic-forms

how do I compute the fundmental domain for a congruence subgroup of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$

This region is important because the theta function $\theta(z) = q^{n^2}$ is invariant under two transformations $z \mapsto z + 1$ and $z \to - \frac{1}{4z}$, and these two generate the congruence subgroup  $\Gamma_0(4)$.

I know there is an algorithm for any Fuchsian group. Here is an erroneous comutation of the fundamental domain.  It has too many cusps.

[image]

---

I found a [blog](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/quivers-versus-quilts) with a picture of what could be the fundamental domain of $\Gamma_0(2)$.  Therefore the domain for $\Gamma_0(4)$ could be related.  I know that $[SL(2,\mathbb{Z}): \Gamma_0(2)]= 3$ and $[SL(2,\mathbb{Z}): \Gamma_0(4)]= 6$ but I can't figure out which two copies to join.  And ther's no derivation for this particular case.

[image]

Comment: It would help if your question contained a bit more information such as the definition of $\Gamma_0(4)$.

Comment: Use the fundamental domain for SL(2,$\mathbb Z$), and look at the cosets for the congruence subgroup.  (I think I illustrated this procedure in my modular forms notes, for example.)

Comment: @kimball can you provide link? I think there's an easy trick for congruence groups, I am reading out of notes of Zagier who leaves it as exercise. I need area of fundamental region in order to show there's only one modular form of weight 4.

Comment: My notes are [here](http://www.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/mfs/), see Example 3.4.11 for the case of $\Gamma_0(2)$.  I leave $\Gamma_0(4)$ as an exercise.  But it has index 6 in SL(2,$\mathbb Z$) so the area will be 6 times that of a fundamental domain for SL(2,$\mathbb Z$).  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1316464/11323

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, we can obtain a fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(4)$ by taking a fundamental domain for $\newcommand{\SL}{\operatorname{SL}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \SL_2(\Z)$ and translating by coset representatives for $\SL_2(\Z)/\Gamma_0(4)$.

First let's recover the fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(2)$ that you linked. We begin with the fundamental domain $D_1$ for $\SL_2(\Z)$ below.

$\hspace 6cm$[image]

Taking the coset representatives
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
for $\SL_2(\Z)/\Gamma_0(2)$ and translating $D_1$ by each element, we obtain the fundamental domain $D_2$ for $\Gamma_0(2)$ below.

$\hspace 6cm$[image]

To obtain a fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(4)$, we choose a representative $A$ for the nontrivial coset of $\Gamma_0(2)/\Gamma_0(4)$ and then form $D_2 \cup (A \cdot D_2)$.

To get a fundamental domain similar to the one in the picture you drew, we want an element that acts on $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} i$ in the same way that $S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ acts on $i$. So we conjugate $S$ by the element $\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right)$ that takes $i$ to $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} i$:
\begin{align*}
A := \left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right)^{-1}
= \left(\begin{array}{rr} 1 & -1\\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right) \, .
\end{align*}
Note that $A \in \Gamma_0(2) \setminus \Gamma_0(4)$, as required. Multiplying each of the coset representatives for $\Gamma_0(2)$ by $A$, we obtain the coset representatives
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
 \end{array}\right),
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1
 \end{array}\right),
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
 -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0
 \end{array}\right),
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & -1 \\
 2 & -1
 \end{array}\right),
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1
 \end{array}\right),
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 2
 \end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
with the corresponding fundamental domain below.

$\hspace 6cm$[image]

As a note, if you only need the area of a fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(4)$, we don't actually have to construct the fundamental domain. Since $[\SL_2(\Z) : \Gamma_0(4)] = 6$, then
$$
\newcommand{\vol}{\operatorname{vol}}
\vol(\Gamma_0(4)) = [\SL_2(\Z) : \Gamma_0(4)] \vol(\SL_2(\Z)) = 6 \cdot \frac{\pi}{3} = 2\pi \, .
$$

(All these images were made with SageMath. [Here's a link to a SageMathCell with the commands](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJztUtFOgzAUfV_CP9zMlyLdpExfTHhe9u4bIaTDDhoL7Uon4-9tgblplMUY3yQk9B7uuefknq4hhjWtKoqI783akhuWvTJtGosnGwyIBM1eG7RY-f5dhGFT73jNTZd6s0LT7txLguluQ2xX2Smmt1LwPDOa07oQDE3QMOhim0shdTx3anMMVKiSxuHywbo10TcjJ71g2HEh4id9YFfmN6VskSGBsexjxet4ES6JO9JjTNypO4OdA20fbRTLTaap4TJ2K_Vmmqlsf6DP_Zq8GdgnsYywf0mKR8gVGBbkEhvKAQ3BbjHtx_WT1ogJH3ZSAxPAa3iXSZ3oDVT0hYES0vQ9fcZZiCJrSbnMNVUlzxtka_ffsschzeMg3hLcRrhdOS0LL2luZP1J8-K-pAOrILiIcDHJOl-ckaQg-DrIk4crQU3OODn6Ye7qV5kbt2KUnLKL3Cf1x_Cs0cTc2l18CG86t_v_3P46tzeOgIA-&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).)